# Apple sign in rejection

Tags: appstore-approval

I have uploaded an app with Apple SignIn, In that after sign in success we are taking user info like First name, Last name , email But i got a rejection from apple .

> 5. 1.1 Legal: Privacy - Data Collection and Storage
>      Guideline 5.1.1 - Legal - Privacy - Data Collection and Storage
>      We noticed that your app requires users to register with personal information that is not directly relevant to your app's core functionality. Specifically, the following fields are required but do not appear to be directly relevant to your app's core functionality:
>
>    - First and Last Name (when using Sign In with Apple)
>    - Email (when using Sign In with Apple)
>        Name and Email are supplied by Sign In with Apple, so asking for these separately is not appropriate. We encourage you to utilize Sign In with Apple and honor its intentions, to respect users privacy and personal information.
>        Next Steps
>        To resolve this issue, please either remove all required fields that are not relevant to the app or make those fields optional. Information requested during registration must be relevant to the features the app provides.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because App store approval is off-topic for Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/appstore-approval/info,  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/1187415.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately it is correct that this question is not programming related. You may want to try Apple's official developer forums to solve similar problems though they generally do not give any more information than their explanation. You may try appealing to their rejection and getting more information.

Comment: Vikas tried to help you below by squeezing a programming question out of your question. If you officially change your question to include something like this "...this is the rejection:..... So it seems like I must not re-request these information. How can I store this information at the first time? I tried ...this ... and this... but it did not work..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Save all the data in keychain When you get the success data `didCompleteWithAuthorization` and after use keychain data.

```
 func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
    if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {

        // Create an account in your system.
        // For the purpose of this demo app, store the these details in the keychain.
        KeychainItem.currentUserIdentifier = appleIDCredential.user
        KeychainItem.currentUserFirstName = appleIDCredential.fullName?.givenName
        KeychainItem.currentUserLastName = appleIDCredential.fullName?.familyName
        KeychainItem.currentUserEmail = appleIDCredential.email

        print("User Id - \(appleIDCredential.user)")
        print("User Name - \(appleIDCredential.fullName?.description ?? "N/A")")
        print("User Email - \(appleIDCredential.email ?? "N/A")")
        print("Real User Status - \(appleIDCredential.realUserStatus.rawValue)") 
}
}
```

For changing any state of credentials you can track with the following code.

```
 let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
appleIDProvider.getCredentialState(forUserID: KeychainItem.currentUserIdentifier) { (credentialState, error) in
    switch credentialState {
    case .authorized:
        // The Apple ID credential is valid.
        break
    case .revoked:
        // The Apple ID credential is revoked.
        break
    case .notFound:
        // No credential was found, so show the sign-in UI.
        }
    default:
        break
    }
}
```